# Advance formula field nested conditions

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to get done by formula field.

If Deal type = A or B or C AND Deal sub type = 2 THEN exp date should be current date + 730 days.
If Deal type = A or B or C AND Deal sub type = 1 THEN exp date should be current date + 365 days.
If Deal type = A or B or C AND Deal sub type = 0 THEN exp date should be same.

Here is my formula which I am getting error

> error. Found 'IF'

```
IF
AND (
     OR (
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "A"),
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "B",
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "C")

        ),
(ISPICKVAL(Deal_sub_type__c, '2'), exp_date__c + 730, exp_date__c)
)
IF
AND (
     OR (
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "A"),
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "B",
           (ISPICKVAL(Deal_Type__c), "C")

        ),
(ISPICKVAL(Deal_sub_type__c, '1'), exp_date__c + 365, exp_date__c)
)
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: The syntax for the `IF` function is `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. You don't have any parentheses, and it's not clear what value should be assigned for other Deal Types.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am calculating the expiration date based on the deal sub type and only for these three deals. Other deals's exp date will not be impacted.

Comment: Earlier i used case statement and I messed up the parentheses, so I removed it. Now trying with IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because the `IF` function is a parameterized function that takes three arguments.

```
IF(<expression_to_evaluate>, <expression_is_true>, <expression_is_false>)
```

Example:

```
IF(AND(Payment_Due_Date__c < TODAY(),​​Payment_Status__c ="UNPAID"), "PAYMENT OVERDUE", ​null)
```

You need to wrap your other logic in parentheses so that the syntax is correct.

[Formula function documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)